# Jquery Fade when page content is loaded

Tags: jquery, css

I want to create an effect in jquery that waits until every element of my page is done loading before anything is displayed. The same effect is done [here](http://www.zaum.co.uk/).

As you can see, when you load or refresh the page, the background color appears and when everything is finished loading, jquery fades it in. My website is: http://www.vitaminjdesign.com

Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way to do this (which is, incidentally, the same method the Zaum website uses) is to create a div that covers the entire visible canvas and fade that OUT once the page fully loads. Here's the code:

```
#mask {
    position:absolute; 
    top:0; 
    left:0; 
    right:0; 
    bottom:0; 
    background-color:red; 
    z-index:99;
}
```

And the HTML:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Mask Example</TITLE>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function () {
    $('#mask').fadeOut('slow');
});
</SCRIPT>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<P>Some text goes here</P>
<IMG src="http://spaceflight.nasa.gov/gallery/images/shuttle/sts-119/hires/s119e008352.jpg" />
<P>And moar text!!</P>
<DIV id="mask"></DIV>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Messing with body opacity is generally considered bad practice and may not be fully supported on some browsers.

Comment: love it, thats exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: I added an ajax loader too. Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

Put this into your CSS file (or directly in the `body` tag):

```
body {
    display: none;
}
```

And the JS has to be (in `head` or `body`):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function() {
        $('body').fadeIn()
    })
</script>
```

The function gets executed when the whole content of the document is loaded.

Comment: He wants it to occur after the all page was loaded, including the pictures.

Comment: Felix you need `$(window).load(function() {` in this case, for the images to load as well.

Comment: yes, exactly. This will simply fade in before it loads, resulting in a choppy animation.

Comment: It does work, which is great, but its not elegant. Its really choppy. Any fixes to make it work smoothly?

Comment: @Nick Craver: Oh thought this also working this way... changed the answer, thx.