# Fade content in after page loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fade

What's the best way to do this, and how do you make it browser-proof? For example, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2178336/jquery-fade-when-page-content-is-loaded) establishes that best practice is to cover your content with an opaque div and fade that out after load. But what if the client has javascript disabled? PHP detection of JS isn't reliable, and if one were to go with the opaque div method you would never see the content in a JS-disabled browser.

Ideas?

Comment: If you are trying to make something work with PHP and be Javascript-independent, your choices are not good.  Flash, Silverlight, ActiveX and HTML5 are also disable-able and browser-specific.  If you have a specific requirement to work on browsers that do not/ will not support Javascript, you should probably abandon attempting animations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set default of the overlay element to `display: none` in css and use `document.write` to insert a style tag in head (after main css) that sets it to display:block. If js disabled will never be seen since the `write` will be ignored.

Another way is to use script in your head to add a class to html tag such as `js_enabled` , make css rule like

```
.overlay { display:none}
.js_enabled .overlay { display:block}
```

Comment: I like this answer, but could you address how or if its possible to handle javascript-disabled fade effects?  I mean, are they even possible with some sort of `<noscripts>` option or something?

Comment: The only way to fade an element without JavaScript is to use css3 animations. But than again, without JavaScript how would you know when the page is loaded?

Comment: don't think there's much you can do dynamically with script disabled

Comment: Noscript?! Gah, the answer was obvious... set the fade element to `display:none` in the stylesheet, then `<noscript><style>#element { display:block; } </style></noscript>` in the head.